# what is the use of 'int' before a method in java?

Tags: java

In the following code we can use 'calculate()' directly but what is the use of 'int' before calculate()?

```
class Rectangle{
    int length, breadth;
    void show(int x, int y){
        length = x;
        breadth = y;
    }
    int calculate(){
        return(length * breadth);
    }
}
public class EnterValuesFromKeyboard{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        rectangle.show(a, b);
        System.out.println(
              " you have entered these values : " +  a  + " and " +  b);
        int area = rectangle.calculate();
        System.out.println(" area of a rectange is  : " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 this question is too noob to be of any real use

Comment: I suggest you get a beginner book for Java, and read through the first several chapters.  And, your question is bad, by having bunch of useless code.  Can't you just trim the code to include something relevant?

Comment: actually i am studying beginner book for java ,so got this little doubt Adrian...

Comment: i dont know why these down votes??
u r not interested in encourage beginners.....

Comment: @srithatsmyname if you look, you will find that the stackoverflow community encourages beginners aplenty, some will maybe argue, too much.  However `this particular question is very weak`, and many people including myself, feel that _you_ should either figure this on your own, through books and online resources or for the least demonstrate that you tried much harder than you apparently have...

Answer (score 2):

that tells the `return` type of the method

```
int calculate(){
  return(length * breadth);
  }
```

In this case, it tells caller that `calculate()` method returns an `int` value.

I would suggest reading [java basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: Tq Nambari ur ans is helpful and ur suggestion is useful.

Answer (score 2):

The first keyword in a function specifies the type of the return value. So in the case of

```
 int calculate(){
  return(length * breadth);
 }
```

The **int** advices that the value to return will be a integer.

Answer (score 2):

After calculate() method invoked, the result will be in int type. This helps u to use the method as a value. 
e.g.: int a = calculate() // the result of calculate() will be assigned to variable a. 
xyz = a + calculate() + b // calculate's return value will join the formular
etc.